# Caption will not go above table with chemstyle

Tags: positioning, captions, chemstyle

Caption refuses to go above the table, even when it is called before `tabular` environment.  A similar issue is mentioned in threads elsewhere, and it has been mentioned in the `chemstyle` documentation that the package makes the positioning of the caption itself irrelevant.  It offers two fixes, depending on whether one uses `float` or `floatrow`.  Neither work, and in any event my caption is stuck below the table, whereas the examples in the chemstyle documentation indicate that the caption should be stuck above the table, and offer solutions to move it below:

> **9.2 Captions above floats**
>
> The scheme float type is generated using
>   either the float or floatrow package. This has the side-effect that
>   the placement of captions for floats does not depended on where the
>   `\caption` command comes inside the floating environment. If you wish
>   to alter the placement of captions, the mechanism of the underlying
>   package will be needed. There are some subtle differences between the
>   two: although floatrow provides the float macros, they are not all 100
>   % compatible. This document is compiled using floatrow, and so to fix
>   the position of captions the following code is appropriate.
>
> ```
> \begin{table}[ht] 
>   \fbox{First float contents}
>   \caption{A caption below the float contents in the source.}
> \end{table}
> \floatsetup[table]{style=plain} 
> \begin{table}[ht]
>   \fbox{Second floatcontents}
>   \caption{A second caption below the float contents in the source.}
> \end{table}
> ```
>
> Using the float package, the same effect is
>   achieved using:
>
> ```
> \begin{table}[ht]
>   \fbox{First float contents}
>   \caption{A caption below the float contents in the source.}
> \end{table}
> \floatstyle{plain}
> \restylefloat{table}
> \begin{table}[ht]
>   \fbox{Second float contents}
>   \caption{A second caption below the float contents in the source.}
> \end{table}
> ```

My document:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chemstyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Blah.}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    Heading\\[1ex]  
    \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    Stuff\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular} 
    \label{meh}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Removing the chemstyle package fixes the problem... but obviously I'm using it for other things.

Comment: Something weird is going on.  When I compile this user's example: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=10301, his complaint being that the caption is ABOVE the table, it appears BELOW the table for me...

Comment: Seems I have fixed this.  Thanks to ... (wow, I found the answer on this website but it's either me or the search is very bad because I can't even find it again).  Anyway, the suggestion was to use \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}.  After including the floatrow package instead of the float package, this worked.

Comment: Your MWE works fine for me and places the caption above the table. I am using TeXLive2011, so wondering if you are using older versions of some packages?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610437/caption-will-not-go-above-table-with-chemstyle?noredirect=1). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: @user973066 This is 'works for me' too, again with TL 2011. We could do to see a log (or at least `\listfiles` output) to understand this issue.